# How to insert data on CREATE TABLE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, kotlin

In my application using Kotlin and SQLite I want to create a table `pointTable` and immediately insert first data, but a runtime error occurs. I want to catch the error code, but it doesn't work. What's wrong?

```
lass SqliteHelper(context: Context?, name:String, version:Int):SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, null, version) {

    // create table
    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        try {
            p0?.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)")
            p0?.let {
                initPoint(it)
            }
        } catch (err: Exception) {
            Log.d("test", err.toString())
            Log.d("test", err.stackTraceToString())
        }
    }

    fun initPoint(wd: SQLiteDatabase) {
        wd.execSQL("insert into pointTable(pointValue) values (0)")
        wd.close()
    }

}
```

```
    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase) {
        val sqlArray = arrayOf(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questionTable" +
                    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    " num INT," +
                    " que TEXT," +
                    " abcArr Text," +
                    " opt1 Text, opt2 Text, opt3 Text, opt4 Text," +
                    " ans INT," +
                    " exp TEXT," +
                    " examName TEXT," +
                    " wrong INT, correct INT," +
                    " part1 TEXT, part2 TEXT, part3 TEXT, part4 TEXT, part5 TEXT, part6 TEXT, part7 TEXT )",
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS examTable(examName TEXT, downloadDate TEXT, myApply INT)",
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)"

        )
        sqlArray.forEach {
            p0.execSQL(it)
        }
        initPoint(p0)
    }

    private fun initPoint(wd:SQLiteDatabase){
        wd.execSQL("insert into pointTable(pointValue) values (5)")
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?  What do you mean by "I want to catch the error code, but it doesn't work"?

Comment: it means runtime error. try catch didn't work.

Comment: How do you know that you're getting a runtime error?  Does "runtime error" get printed on your console and nothing else?  I find that hard to believe.  If you're getting more output than that, then it might make a significant difference for us to know exactly what you're getting. Do you know which line of your program is causing the error?  Have you tried running your code in a debugger?  If so, then do you get the same behavior if you step slowly through each line of your code as if you just run it?  Your code seems OK.  If you can't give us more info, I don't know how anyone can help you.

Comment: After doing this and that, I changed p0? to p0, and the code works normally. Let's take a look at why this is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This means that the problem was just a typo and you should have deleted your question and not accept an answer that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Ignore the garbage saying it was a typo. Proven by the answer working with the so called typo.

Comment: @MikeT from the OP's comment: "I changed p0? to p0, and the code works normally" and from your answer: "There is nothing wrong with the code in the onCreate method" Where do you think is the garbage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code in the onCreate method, it works fine. **BUT**, wd.close in the initPoint function may well result in subsequent issues.

That is when you actually try to access the database for the first time it calls `onCreate`, creates the database the table gets added, but then the database is closed (by `wd.close()`) and the closed database is then made available to actually perform the access to the database. The result being an exception because the database is closed. When you rerun the App, as the database now exists then `onCreate` isn't called and the issue appears to have been fixed as now an opened database is returned. However, if the App was distributed then the exception would happen the first time the App is used.

Perhaps consider the following working example based upon the available code (see comments for changes). This adds some additional logging :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dbHelper: SqliteHelper
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dbHelper = SqliteHelper(this,"my_database.db",1)
        var db = dbHelper.writableDatabase // do something as otherwise database will not be created
        // inspect the resultant database schema again
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(db.query("sqlite_master", null,null,null,null,null,null))
    }
}

class SqliteHelper(context: Context?, name:String, version:Int):
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, null, version) {

    // create table
    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        Log.d("test","onCreate invoked") // ADDED
        try {
            p0?.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)")
            p0?.let {
                initPoint(it)
            }
        } catch (err: Exception) {
            Log.d("test", err.toString())
            Log.d("test", err.stackTraceToString())
        }
        //ADDED to inspect the resultant database schema
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(p0?.query("sqlite_master", null,null,null,null,null,null))
    }

    // ADDED as required
    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
    }
    
    fun initPoint(wd: SQLiteDatabase) {
        wd.execSQL("insert into pointTable(pointValue) values (0)")
        //wd.close() //<<<<<<<<<< DELETED as can cause problems be inefficient
    }
}
```

Result output to the log (note first run, which is when the database will be created, subsequent runs will only log as per the MainActivity as the database exists):-

```
2022-11-13 19:02:17.190 D/test: onCreate invoked


2022-11-13 19:02:17.192 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@cf2ef01
2022-11-13 19:02:17.192 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-13 19:02:17.192 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-13 19:02:17.192 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:02:17.192 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:02:17.193 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-13 19:02:17.193 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-13 19:02:17.193 I/System.out: }
2022-11-13 19:02:17.193 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-11-13 19:02:17.193 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-13 19:02:17.193 I/System.out:    name=pointTable
2022-11-13 19:02:17.194 I/System.out:    tbl_name=pointTable
2022-11-13 19:02:17.194 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2022-11-13 19:02:17.194 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)
2022-11-13 19:02:17.194 I/System.out: }
2022-11-13 19:02:17.194 I/System.out: <<<<<


2022-11-13 19:02:17.208 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40841a6
2022-11-13 19:02:17.208 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-13 19:02:17.208 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-13 19:02:17.208 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:02:17.209 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:02:17.209 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-13 19:02:17.209 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-13 19:02:17.209 I/System.out: }
2022-11-13 19:02:17.209 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-11-13 19:02:17.210 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-13 19:02:17.210 I/System.out:    name=pointTable
2022-11-13 19:02:17.210 I/System.out:    tbl_name=pointTable
2022-11-13 19:02:17.211 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2022-11-13 19:02:17.211 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)
2022-11-13 19:02:17.211 I/System.out: }
2022-11-13 19:02:17.211 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

In regard to trapping the error, then the above modified to use the blatantly wrong

```
CREATE NOTAKEYWORDTABLE IF NOT EXISTS pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)
```

uninstalling the App to delete the existing database and running results in the log showing:-

```
2022-11-13 19:10:11.697 D/test: onCreate invoked


2022-11-13 19:10:11.697 E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "NOTAKEYWORDTABLE": syntax error in "CREATE NOTAKEYWORDTABLE IF NOT EXISTS pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)"
2022-11-13 19:10:11.697 D/test: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "NOTAKEYWORDTABLE": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE NOTAKEYWORDTABLE IF NOT EXISTS pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)
2022-11-13 19:10:11.701 D/test: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "NOTAKEYWORDTABLE": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE NOTAKEYWORDTABLE IF NOT EXISTS pointTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pointValue INT)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1841)
        at a.a.so74419125kotlinsqlite.SqliteHelper.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:411)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
        at a.a.so74419125kotlinsqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        
        
2022-11-13 19:10:11.702 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40841a6
2022-11-13 19:10:11.703 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-13 19:10:11.704 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-13 19:10:11.704 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:10:11.704 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:10:11.704 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-13 19:10:11.704 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-13 19:10:11.704 I/System.out: }
2022-11-13 19:10:11.704 I/System.out: <<<<<


2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@7e8b7e7
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out: }
2022-11-13 19:10:11.713 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

Comment: @조영민 just updated answer showing result if there were something wrong.